# Custom module's template not rendering in frontend in magento 2

Tags: layout, template, magento-2.1.7, third-party-module

I am using magento 2.1.7 with default luma theme(fresh magento installation).

I am using a custom module which show call for price option on product details page and category page.

Module's installation and configuration done successfully, but module's template file not rendering in frontend (product page and category page).
Please suggest If there is any issue in layout rendering.

Here is my **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Company_Modulename::css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <css src="Company_Modulename::css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_Modulename::addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" >
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_Modulename::addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.modulename" template="Company_Modulename::modulename_form.phtml" after="product.info.mailto" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

here is my module's **addtocart.phtml** template file path:-

```
app\code\Company\Modulename\view\frontend\templates\addtocart.phtml
```

Please let me know if required more to explain the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your template file path

Comment: @Rakesh: I have updated the template path in my question

Comment: are you using module's `catalog_product_view.xml` file or its from `Magento_Catalog` ??

Comment: I am using module's `catalog_product_view.xml` file